# Jest Snapshot testing Redux & coverage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, jestjs

When snapshot testing a component I want to only test the component itself, not the actions, state or the connecting function that is in Redux. This is because I have tests for these functions in other places.

This messes up your code coverage because it expects that you test all functions.

For example:

```
export const EarningsInfo = ({ close }) => ( /* ... */ );

const mapStateToProps = _ => ({});

const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => ({
  close: _ => dispatch(closeModal()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(EarningsInfo);
```

Jest is expecting that you test

1. `earningsInfo`
2. `mapStateToProps`
3. `mapActionsToProps`
4. `connect`

So if you have a simple test like this:

```
import { EarningsInfo } from '../components/EarningsInfo';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <EarningsInfo close={ () => null } />
  ).toJSON();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Code coverage reports that you are only testing 25% of the file. I am sure this is working as intended.

My question is two fold

1. Am I correct in my thinking that `mapStateToProps`, `mapActionsToProps` and `connect` shouldn't need to be tested.
2. Is there a way to ignore a function name in for coverage purposes?

Comment: Actually after looking at this http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#connected-components I believe I am right in thinking the tests should be on the component itself, not the other functions. So really what would be the best way to ignore function names in Jest?

Comment: Personally, I would export the `EarningsInfo` component as a named export (in addition to the default export of the connected component) and just test the raw `EarningsInfo` component. Then have a few integration tests that make sure things are wired together properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. `connect` should not be tested as `react-redux`'s own tests already cover this. If `mapStateToProps` or `mapActionsToProps` have any non-standard / complicated / business logic then it may make sense to test them.
2. Yes, but it can be a bit fragile - http://blog.dmbcllc.com/es2015-code-coverage-and-jest-react-js-unit-testing/

Don't worry about 100% code coverage, focus on what is critical AND can be tested well/easily with unit testing.